# Is this an abuse of the quotient rule?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, matrix-decomposition

I have seen it said (Lebedev and Cloud, "Tensor Analysis", pg. 30) that given two non-zero vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ the square matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is *uniquely* defined by the linear operation $\mathbf{Ax=y}$, such that for any arbitrary non-zero vector $\mathbf{u}$

$$\mathbf{Au=Bu}\rightarrow \mathbf{A=B} \tag{1}$$

The authors also phrase this by saying that if $\mathbf{A}$ is a second order tensor then (1) is true.

Ok, so then for any non-zero vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ and the relation

$$\mathbf{Au=Bv}$$

May I just rewrite the RHS as follows

$$\mathbf{Au=BD(v)D(u)^{-1}u}$$

(Where the notation $\mathbf{D(q)}$ indicates a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the elements of the vector $\mathbf{q}$ in parentheses.)

And, by (1), conclude that, if $\mathbf{A}$ is a second order tensor, then

$$\mathbf{A=BD(v)D(u)^{-1}}$$

Comment: Maybe I'm just being picky here, but $u = (1,0)$ is a non-zero vector but $$D(u) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ is non-invertible.

Comment: The claims in the first five lines of your question are just plain **wrong**.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Deepest apologies to the authors if this novice has misrepresented their explanation. Please consider clarifying what the authors say in an answer, or saying something constructive.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out with the statement
$$
Au = Bu \to A = B.
$$
As written, it looks like
$$
\forall u(Au = Bu \to A = B),
$$
and that is how you are interpreting it, too, but in fact, that is false (e.g., take $u$ a vector with all ones, and let $A$ and $B$ have the same columns, just permuted).

The correct statement is
$$
\forall u(Au = Bu) \to A = B.
$$